# How to send a notification when Firebase database has been updated?

Tags: android, notifications, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The latest launch of Firebase notifications feature allows to manually give the time and content of notification. Is it possible to automate it so that notification is received every time a particular variable is changed in the Firebase database?

Comment: need help. I want the same thing will you help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to setup a GCM (Switched to FCM now) server that handles all that. But I also do wish that there was a simple way of setting that up without needing to build a full server.

There is a [friendlyping](https://github.com/googlesamples/friendlyping) application that helped me set the XPMM server.

I think the current Firebase Notifications are very much in its early days. It doesn't provide many of the functionalities of [Batch.com](https://batch.com/) or [Parse Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)... yet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply Hamid. I didn't want to get into the technicalities of GCM therefore I implemented the notifications using a service. This service listen on the Firebase database and sends a notification whenever new data is added there.

Comment: Please share the code so that others will also know the solution